# jest errors with not a not a function for promises

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm attempting to write **jest** tests for promises.

calculateSquare() returns a promise.

testing this within the script with console.log, this function resolves and rejects as expected.

**square.js**

```js
const calculateSquare = (number) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (typeof number !== "number") {
            return reject(new Error("NaN"));
        }
        const square = number * number;
        resolve(square);
    });
    return promise;
};

// testing locally
calculateSquare(3).then((value) => { console.log(value) });
calculateSquare("3").catch((err) => { console.log(err.message) });

exports = { calculateSquare }
```

but when I try to run the jest tests below:

**square.test.js**

```js
const { calculateSquare } = require("./square");

describe("test calculateSquare function", () => {
    test("2 squared is 4", () => {
        return expect(calculateSquare(2)).resolves.toEqual(4);
    });

    test("'2' throws exception", () => {
        return expect(calculateSquare("2")).rejects.toMatch("NaN");
    });
});
```

my tests fail with this error:

> TypeError: calculateSquare is not a function

Could you please help me understand why this is "not a function" when it is and what's the right way to write these tests?

thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need to do the below in `square.js`

```
module.exports = { calculateSquare }
```